# How can I estimate the required T/O power for propeller aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff

How can I estimate the maximum required take-off power for a propeller aircraft with the following available data?

- Wing surface S
- Max. lift coefficient in T/O configuration cL
- Take-off distance available d (regardless of obstacle clearance etc.)
- MTOW
- Airfield altitude (let us assume MSL)

Is the data available even enough?

Answer (score 2):

You need takeoff speed (from the lift coefficient, wing surface and altitude) and the time in which you need to achieve it (before you run off the runway). That'll give you the needed acceleration ($a = \frac{\Delta v}{s}$)

From that you can know how much force the prop must generate ($F = ma$).

Add some margin to account for friction losses.